# I want to replace the setInterval with a var

Tags: javascript

I'm making a snake game but some problems have emerged.

Almost everything is working fine but the problem is that I have to stop one `setInterval` when another is being executed. I think that I should use `clearInterval`.

I want the red rect to start moving when I press the right arrow key, but to use the `setInterval` as a `var` so I can replace the `var` with `clearInterval`.

What should I do?

```
<html>
<body>
    <canvas id="gamecanvas" width="1330" height="625"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas;
        var canvasContext;

        window.onload = function () {
            canvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas");
            canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
        }

        function both() {
            moveSnake();
            drawEvery();
        };

        function moveSnake() {
            snakeX = snakeX + snakeSpeedX;

            if (snakeX + 10 >= 500 + 400) {
                snakeX = 450;
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.changedir, false);


        function changedir(event) {
            var code = event.keyCode;
            //right arrow key
            if (code == 39) {
                //this set interval needs to be replaced by a var.
                setInterval(both, 1000 / 30)
            };
        }

        function drawEvery() {
            canvasContext.fillStyle = "yellow";
            canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            canvasContext.fillStyle = "black";
            canvasContext.fillRect(canvasX, canvasY, 500, 500);

            canvasContext.fillStyle = "red";
            canvasContext.fillRect(snakeX, snakeY, 20, 20);

            canvasContext.fillStyle = "green";
            canvasContext.fillRect(500, 200, 20, 20);

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) returns an `intervalId`, which you can use to clear the interval later on

```
    //this set interval needs to be replaced by a var.
    var interval = setInterval(both, 1000/30);
```

later you can use

```
clearInterval(interval)
```

One thing to note here is that the variable must be declared in the same scope where you are using clearInterval